# Having trouble converting a X509 Certificate to Base64

Tags: java, base64, x509certificate

I have a `X509 Certificate` and I want to store it in a `MySQL DB` instead of saving the file. Therefore, I thought it is better to convert the certificate to `base64` and store it. I have done the forward and reverse of this conversion however, I did not get true results.

I'm using `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate` and import `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` as follows:

```
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.getInstance(new FileInputStream(certFile));
System.out.println("Vigencia: "+cert.getNotAfter());
System.out.println("Inicio: "+cert.getNotBefore());
String cert64 = bytes2String(Base64.encodeBase64(cert.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
System.out.println("Cert 64: "+ cert64);
String certRegreso = bytes2String(Base64.decodeBase64(cert64.getBytes()));
System.out.println("Cert Regreso: "+ certRegreso);
X509Certificate certNuevo = X509Certificate.getInstance(certRegreso.getBytes());
```

Comment: Is it Apache's commons codec `Base64`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the javadocs X509Certificate implements Serializable so why not use the much simpler solution and store it as a byte array? Something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(certificate);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray(); 
bos.close();
```

And now just store the byte array as a blob. To recreate it you can just use:

```
ByteArrayIntputSream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData);
ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) in.readObject(); 
bis.close();
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to try the Base64 option first because that's the way it's done in another form of this software (im porting an application to web) so I don't really want to change the way it's done so they can work together without any problems.